# How to control http request that targets Async operation

Tags: node.js, express, promise, rethinkdb

I am trying to fetch user data during a login process.
Data stored in rethinkDb.
The flow is:

•   Request is routed to a controller (via express)

•   Controller choose correct handler

•   Handler call the dao.get():

```
  login: function (email, password, res) {
        var feedback = daouser.get(email);
        if (feedback.success) {
            var user = feedback.data;
            //Do some validatios...
        }       
        res.status = 200;
        res.send(feedback);
    },
```

•   dao.get() code is:

```
get: function (email) {        
    var feedback = new Feedback();
    self.app.dbUsers.filter({email: email}).run().then(function (result) {
        var user = result[0];
        feedback.success = true;
        feedback.data = user;
        return feedback;
    });
}
```

But since the call is via a promise, the dao.get return before the actual “Then” function is call and the controller gets **undefined** feedback…

Something wrong with my design…

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var feedback = daouser.get(email);`

You can't do a synchronous assignment here, since .get is asynchronous. Also, notice that you are not returning anything from .get, that's why it's undefined.
I'd make all of this a promise chain.

```
get: function (email) {        
var feedback = new Feedback();

// RETURN is important here, this way .get() return a promise instead of undefined
return self.app.dbUsers.filter({email: email}).run().then(function (result) {
    var user = result[0];
    feedback.success = true;
    feedback.data = user;
    return feedback;
});
```

}

```
login: function (email, password, res) {
    //return the promise again, so login will be chainable too
    return daouser.get(email)
    // You can chain another then here, because you returned a promise from .get above
    // Your then function will be called with the return from the previous then, which is 'feedback'
    .then(function(feedback) {
      if (feedback.success) {
        var user = feedback.data;
        //Do some validatios...
      }       
      res.status = 200;
      res.send(feedback);
  }
},
```